# class or function for associative array in php

Tags: php

I  have two function with are similar but the way how they return the array result is different:

```
search..($user) {
    return array( "name" => $name, "age"=> $age);
}
```

and the second:

```
search..($user) {
    return array( "firstname" => $name, "myage"=> $age);
}
```

Is there any way to write a class or anything to make them in one function or such thing?

Comment: don't put java tag to php questions

Answer (score 1):

What about factorizing like this:

```
search..($user, $nametag, $agetag) {
    return array($nametag => $name, $agetag => $age);
}
```

And then calling the function like:

```
$arr = search..($user, "name", "age");
$arr = search..($user, "firstname", "myage");
```

#### EDIT

If you have many parameters you can encapsulate them in a single associative array, so you won't have to worry about long/explosing method signatures:

```
search..($user, $tags) {
    return array($tags["name"] => $name, $tags["age"] => $age, ...);
}

$tags = array ("name" => "firstname", "age" => "myage", ...);
$arr = search..($user, $tags);
```

I don't see other cleaner options.. If you don't like the tags overhead I'd consider to redesign your logic flow.

### EDIT2

You can encapsulate the mapping logic in a class:

```
<?php

// classe de base, avec des propriétés et des méthodes membres
class UserSearch {

   var $tagMapping;

   var $name;
   var $age;
   var ...

   function UserSearch ($tagMapping) 
   {
       $this->tagMapping = $tagMapping;
   }

   function search($user, $tags)
   {
       return array($this->tagMapping["name"] => $this->name, 
                    $this->tagMapping["age"] => $this->age,
                    ...);
   }

}

?>
```

Comment: Should probably add a third parameter $agetag too.

Comment: @Grimbode I read your comment while editing the answer. You're right, I hand't seen it at the very first glance, thanks.

Comment: Yes but in that case if i have around 20 parameters, doesnt make any sense to add 20 params in a function, i would like to make it more efficient and clean

Comment: @GoodD, modified the answer accordingly

Comment: Is there any way to write a class for that?

Comment: Yes, you can easily encapsulate the logic in a class. I added the example in my response.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function with a second parameter.
This parameter will be used to set return format.

Example :

```
function search($user, $format)
{
  if ( $format == 'me' )
    return array( "firstname" => $name, "myage"=> $age);
  else
    return array( "name" => $name, "age"=> $age);
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for -1 ?

Comment: I agree that if someone downvotes they should leave a comment as to why they downvoted.